# C: Tokenize an array of characters with delimiter strictly as multiple spaces

Tags: c, arrays, delimiter, tokenize, strtok

Using C, I am trying to tokenize an array of characters into separate words, with delimiter as 4 spaces.

For example,
if I have a string

`Hello.My name is    Vivek.You can call    me viv`.

The different tokens should be:

`Hello.My name is`

`Vivek.You can call`

`me viv`

Since, in only 2 places there were 4 consecutive white space characters. Others were less than that.

I have to read a the lines from a file and separate into strings.
After reading from file into an array of characters, I have been trying to do it in a very naive way. i.e. go character by character and keep track of spaces and save the the temporary substring.

This is a snippet of my code from above idea.

```
for(i=0;i<totalLines;i++){

    int x=0;//size of line string
    int spaceCount=0;//current number of spaces
    char temp[20];
    temp[0]='\0';
    int m=0;
    int isprevSpace=0;

    while(fileRead[i][x]!='\0'){
        if(isspace(fileRead[i][x]) && spaceCount>=3){
            printf("%s\n",temp );
            m=0;
            temp[m]='\0';
            spaceCount=0;
        }else if(isspace(fileRead[i][x])) {
            if(spaceCount==0){
                temp[m]=fileRead[i][x];
                temp[m+1]='\0';
                m++;
            }
            spaceCount++;
            isprevSpace=1;
        }
        else{
            temp[m]=fileRead[i][x];
            temp[m+1]='\0';
            m++;
            isprevSpace=0;
        }
        x++;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that I have to keep track of too many variables for not so huge a task.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I had no luck using strtok as well.

Comment: Get rid of the inner loop (i is constant) by putting it into a separate function, which handles only one line.

Comment: `strtok` won't work in this case. Don't think of `strtok` for now.